# What happened to the Rakshasi who breastfed lord Krishna?

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana

### [Video](https://youtu.be/X9WbC8_Txhw&t=1190s)

At 19:50 onwards

**So what happened to her in the video? 
 Why did she die?** [How can someone die when she is breastfeeding?]

Comment: That is what is Krishna’s mahima :D

Comment: @Archit what do you mean by "mahima". :-)

Comment: Mahima means Greatness

Comment: That's the God's leela. He'll kill someone just via breastfeeding and even make a mere arrow to make it as a *nimitt* to end his purpose on earth! The sweet past times of the Lord are incomprehensible for us human minded wits.

Comment: @Vivikta yes, but how did he killed her, or what happened while she was breastfeeding lord

Comment: SrimanMadvacharya said that their 2 jivas in pootana, one is urvashi due to curse she was present in the rakshashi body and another is oootana rakshashi herself, the one which attained moksha by feeding milk to  krishna is actually Urvashi and not rakshashi pootana..She is past incarnation of sister of mahabali when Vamana avaatara of vishnu went in to collect alms his body is like that of boy with golden color sun. seeing the beautty of the boy, pootana i.e. Urvashi inthe body of pootana wanted to feed the beautiful resplendent boy with her breast milk

Comment: and after mahabali was taken by the foot of the lord and sent to some lower lokha.. pootana the rakshashi taught on seeing the same lord that she should feed him with breast milk with poison, whatever one aspire in taught also that lord know eventually she gave breast milk in her next life to lord sri krishna

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer to why Pūtanā died is because of Bhagwan Shri Kṛṣṇa’s greatness. **He being God, sucked the life out of her** while she was nursing him. Let’s look at how the Purāṇas describe Bhagwan sucking her life out of her:

> Kṛṣṇa, laying hold of the breast with both hands, **sucked it with such violence, that he drained it of the life**; and the hideous Pūtanā, roaring aloud, and giving way in every joint, fell on the ground expiring
> -*Viṣṇu Purāṇa* 5.5
>
> Taking Śri Kṛṣṇa into her lap there, that cruel woman put into the baby’s mouth, her dreadful breast besmeared with deadly poison. Squeezing it hard with both his hands, the Lord full of indignation forthwith **sucked the poison along *with her (very) life***
> -*Śrimad Bhagavatam*, 10th Skandha, Chapter 6.9-10

And a similar account of sucking her life finds mention in the Harivamsa Purana, Vishnu Parva, Chapter 6, verse 26

Also as per the [Srimad Bhagavatam 10.6.33-44](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/6/), Putana’s sins are wiped off (and because of nursing him like a mother) she attains the Lord’s supreme abode just the way Yashoda and Devaki would.

---

<sup>Note: The [translation by Gita Press Gorakhpur](https://archive.org/details/bhagavatapuranagitapress_201907/page/n1037/mode/2up) for the Srimad Bhagavata Purāṇa has been referred to</sup>

Comment: You can add that Putana attained Moksha.

Comment: @Surya how did she attained moksha, she was evil.

Comment: @Dark Knight due to the fact that she breastfed the Supreme Lord, her karmas were destroyed at that instant when he sucked her soul, and therefore she attained Moksha.

Comment: @Surya no mention of her moksha in the Puranas. What to do?

Comment: @Archit what, no, her Moksha is mentioned in the very same chapter of Bhagavata Purana which you have quoted!

Comment: @Archit Check Bhagavatam 10.6.33-44

Comment: @Archit see the last verse "Ya Etat **Putana Moksham**  Krsnasya Arbhakam Adbhutam"

Comment: Cool! Maybe could you highlight that section as well?

Comment: @Archit Well technically the question is what happened to her... So yeah.. but whatever suits you 

Comment: your welcome @Archit

Comment: @Archit well yes (if you can). But I read both verse I didn't find any thing about moksha.

Comment: @Archit will this work for every one, if lord killed someone will he/she attain Moksha.